# Загрузка картинок yii2

Tags: php, yii2, fileupload

при загрузке картинок на сервер, если в совокупности у них большой весь, выходит

> ошибка `Bad Request (#400)
>   Не удалось проверить переданные данные.
>   The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.`

при загрузке маленьких картинок все нормально. в `php.ini` тоже все ок, ощущение что именно yii2 не дает

Comment: Покажите что у вас в php.ini и стоят ли права на запись в папку с вложениями?

Comment: может превышен `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: Стек-трейс YII2 показывает проблему на своей стороне? Если нет, то проблема в конфигурации вебсервера.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, проблема оказалось в максимально допустимым количеством времени ожидания в php.ini

Comment: закройте вопрос как решеный

Answer (score 1):

проблема оказалось в максимально допустимым количеством времени ожидания в php.ini